# Was Plutarch Heavensbee based on any real-life figure?

Tags: inspiration, the-hunger-games

<sup>As a follow-up to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110460/was-caesar-flickerman-based-on-any-real-tv-presenter) about Caesar Flickerman...</sup>

### Was the character of [Plutarch Heavensbee](http://thehungergames.wikia.com/wiki/Plutarch_Heavensbee) based on any real person?

This time I'm more interested in his film portrayal by the late [Philip Seymour Hoffman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_Seymour_Hoffman) than in what Suzanne Collins was thinking when she wrote him, although the latter would also be interesting if any evidence exists.
The role of Head [Gamemaker](http://thehungergames.wikia.com/wiki/Gamemaker), the man in charge of running the Hunger Games (which are, at the end of the day, a television show), involves organising the filming, the positioning of prizes and traps, the timing of events, and the projection of everything to the masses. I always thought this must be quite similar to that of a real-life film director or producer - of whom Hoffman must have met a great many during his [long career](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_Seymour_Hoffman_on_stage_and_screen)! I got the impression while watching him that this was a role he knew how to play *very* well from personal experience. Was there anyone in particular on whom he was modelling his performance?

Comment: Autobiographical? :)

Answer (score 4):

### The historical figure Plutarch?

The best I've been able to find is this (non-canonical) speculation from [The Panem Companion](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6eyEAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA219&lpg=PA219&dq=character+inspiration+for+plutarch+heavensbee&source=bl&ots=dKaMyCwRIp&sig=q4HzS_lQsoHxOfKjRkX8pFJngFs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8wPbpg8DKAhWCtBoKHai_BaoQ6AEIXzAN#v=onepage&q=character%20inspiration%20for%20plutarch%20heavensbee&f=false). Its emphasis is on the origin of his *name*, but it includes some discussion of his background, career, and role in the story, so I thought it was interesting enough to merit an answer.

> "Heavensbee" is a portmanteau and proprietary name. In southern vernacular, the phrase "Heavens be!" is a mild expression of surprise. But the name could also come from a line in the "Life of Pericles" (part of *Parallel Lives*), written by Heavensbee's namesake, the historical Plutarch:<sup>1</sup>
>
> > Diopeithes introduced a bill that those who did not recognise the gods, or who taught theories of the *heavens, be* prosecuted.
>
> A Greek historian, biographer, essayist, and Platonic philosopher best known for his *Parallel Lives* and *Moralia*, the historical Plutarch was born to a Greek family under the name Ploutarchos, and was renamed upon becoming a Roman citizen. This may suggest that the Hunger Games' Plutarch came from somewhere outside the Capitol and took a Capitol name to avoid suspicion as he plotted the Second Rebellion;<sup>2</sup> more likely, however, it is the historical Plutarch's work, not his background, that served as the inspiration for the Hunger Games' character.
>
> The historical Plutarch focused most of his adult life on pointing out the moral deficiencies and inadequacies of Roman officials. [...] Plutarch was not concerned with the accurate recording of history so much as the influence of character, good or bad, on the lives and destinies of men.
>
> Similarly, the Hunger Games' Plutarch worked to expose (and depose, in the case of Coriolanus Snow!) corrupt officials. He did this much in the same way the historical Plutarch did: just as Plutarch was interested in preserving and telling people's stories through popular writing (i.e., the *Lives*), Plutarch Heavensbee is interested in displaying and telling people's stories through reality TV programming (the Games, his proposed singing show).

---

<sup>1</sup> OK, this bit is kinda far-fetched. But read on - the comparison with the historical figure Plutarch does sound interesting!

<sup>2</sup> See this question: [Where is Plutarch Heavensbee originally from?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52625/where-is-plutarch-heavensbee-originally-from)

Comment: Just when I think I'm looking at another dreary question attempting to invent trivia, along comes this excellent answer to show me I don't know everything yet.

Answer (score 2):

This is addressed in the special edition of the books that contains the 10th anniversary interview with Suzanne Collins. There is a question regarding what inspired a gladiator-like arena:

> SC: A fascination with the gladiator movies of my childhood, particularly *Spartacus*. Whenever it ran, I'd be glued to the set. My dad would get out *Plutarch's Lives* and read me passages from "Life of Crassus" since Spartacus, being a slave, didn't rate his own book.

/--/

> SC: Plutarch is the namesake of the biographer Plutarch, and he's one of the few characters who has a sense of the arch of history. He's never lived in a world without the Hunger Games; it was well established by the time he was born then he rose through the ranks to become Head Gamemaker.

[Plutarch's Lives/Parallel Lives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_Lives) and the antique in general are overall mentioned as major sources of inspiration for Collins. I don't think there is any relation between the character and the historical person, other than that the former was named after the latter.